# Sharing State Amongst TestMethods in MSTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

How do I share state amongst TestMethods in MSTest.  These tests would be run as Ordered Tests and in sequence.

```
    private TestContext testContext;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return this.testContext; }
        set { this.testContext = value;}
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        bool subscribed = true;
        TestContext.Properties.Add("subscribed", subscribed);
        Assert.IsTrue(subscribed == true, string.Format("Subscribed...{0}", this.GetHashCode()));
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void GenerateEvent()
    {
        bool subscribed = (bool)TestContext.Properties["subscribed"];
        Assert.IsTrue(subscribed == true, string.Format("Subscribed...{0}", this.GetHashCode()));

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally speaking, requiring tests to depend upon other tests and to run in any sort of sequence is bad. Each test should be atomic and independent -- able to run by itself. Any common setup code among a group of tests should be in the SetUp() method

Comment: Chad, I agree...
But this a very specific case where I had to simulate a functional flow [which is decomposed of sequential steps] using MSTest for doing Load Test (again using MSTest).

Comment: Vyas: Then this is an integration test and you should consider treating it as such. Different rules apply to integration tests. Consider one test with the whole flow, perhaps

Comment: @chadmyers - I'd +1 the comment if I could ;-p

Comment: Chad,
Strictly speaking, as you rightly pointed out, what I'm trying to is not unit testing at all.  I want to take these tests [steps] and use the load testing infrastructure on top.  Problem is, with one single test for the whole flow does not give me performance figures for each of the steps.

Comment: Marc, I'm trying to solve a problem here. Currenlty, it's just a prototype. If unit testing gurus direct me how to do what I need without violating principles and heuristics - within the constraints of the tool, I'm all for it. :)

Comment: Actually, this part of my earlier - unfortunately unanswered - question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206890/defining-slas-for-wcf-services

Answer (score 1):

Vyas, I agree with Chad that you're still doing it wrong.

That said, you can look into using the TestContext object.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/vstsqualitytools/archive/2006/01/10/511030.aspx

Comment: Chris,
TestContext is not shared amongst TestMethod(s).  A new instance of TestContext is provided to each TestMethod (as they're both called on different instances) And this is my primary problem.  That's what the code highlights.  Apologies for the ambiguity. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

As Chad had pointed out, it seems that I have no alternative but to use a single test [For once the tool is forcing me to do the right thing ;)] to test the whole flow.

Seems that I could use TestContext.BeginTimer & EndTimer to time each call in the method.

Here's the link to MSDN Forum where I received this answer

Answer (score 1):

You can share data between test methods using static members.

For example:

```
private static List<string> SharedValues = new List<string>();

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
   SharedValues.Add("Awesome!");
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
   SharedValues.Add("Thanks for the answer!");
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod3()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(SharedValues.Contains("Awesome!"));
    Assert.IsTrue(SharedValues.Contains("Thanks for the answer!"));
}
```

Copy this code and create a new ordered test, testing TestMethod1,TestMethod2,TestMethod3. It'll pass!

Answer (score 0):

You could share information across tests by storing it in class-level static fields or properties instead of TestContext. That way, there's only one copy. Additionally, anything one test puts into these fields or properties would be available to any subsequent tests.

Having said that... ordered and/or inter-dependent tests are still evil.